# What is the correct way of using Symfony validation?

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I'm working with an existing `Symfony` application which I have (not perfectly) updated from `Symfony 2.3` to `2.7`.

I want to update an existing violation and then add some more.

The current class looks a bit like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class RFQConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($entity, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if ($entity->$entityMethod()) {
            $this->context->addViolationAt(
                $entity->getTarget(),
                'Can’t do this!',
                array(),
                null
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Symfony documentation suggests replacing addViolationAt() with:

```
$this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
    ->setParameter('%string%', $value)
    ->addViolation();
```

However, I can't find the `buildViolation` in the Context.

```
ConstraintValidator->context (Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextValidator)
```

doesn't have a method `buildViolation`

`ConstraintValidator` has a method `buildViolation`, however, it has been deprecated since version 2.5.

Comment: Take a look at `Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface`. It has the `buildViolation` method. I think, that an instance of this interface is returned but the phpdoc is not updated correctly.